# Can't log android emulator launched with android 7.1.1

Tags: android, android-emulator, logcat

To log my application (log tag is Crime) I usually use bat file like that:

adb disconnect

adb kill-server

adb start-server

adb connect usb

del c:\Users\YURY\Desktop\log.html

adb logcat -c

adb logcat Crime -d *:S > c:\Users\YURY\Desktop\log.html

It work perfectly up for android emulator API 23 and stores log to file on the  desktop. But with android emulator API 25 (7.1.1) I can't start logging.

I recive "No enought memory" message. May be someone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by remoting -d key from adb logcat

Like this:

adb disconnect

adb kill-server

adb start-server

adb connect usb

del c:\Users\YURY\Desktop\log.html

adb logcat -c

adb logcat Crime *:S > c:\Users\YURY\Desktop\log.html

Answer (score 0):

In android Studio

Go to "Tools -> Android -> AVD Manager -> Chose your Emulator  -> Edit -> Advanced Settings -> Change the RAM parameter to 512 Mb or 1024MB

Comment: Not help. After 2048 Mb ram adb report "RAM size too big - reduced to 1500"